# C# :Adapt a program to count the number of marks greater than or equal to 50

Tags: c#, count

my code is where the user needs to enter a mark between and then if the mark is not between 0 and 100, it must ask again, i got that to work , but now the question states : Adapt the above program to also count the number of marks greater than or equal to 50.

How do I do this , I have tried declaring count an integer 0 but I am unsure how 
to implement this.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");
        int mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (mark > 100 || mark < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark,Enter your mark again");
            int newmark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            mark = newmark;
        }
        total += mark;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("sum = " + total);
    double average = (total / 5) * 1.00;
    Console.WriteLine("average = " + average);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `if (mark >= 50) { ++gt50; }` ?

Comment: how do you display the number of marks over 50 back to the user?

Comment: Build the string like this: `"Number of marks over 50 = " + gt50;` and then write it to the console.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use magic numbers. If you want to take more than 5 marks, you'll have to change 2 places in your code. Most reviewers I came across will tell you to start your index at 0 and end condition x < 5 (but that is merely a matter of taste in 99% of the cases) and last: **you should cast `total` to double before dividing** instead of multiplying with 1f  : https://dotnetfiddle.net/fOnBk9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int total = 0;
  int gt50Count = 0;
  for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");
    int mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (mark > 100 || mark < 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark,Enter your mark again");
      int newmark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      mark = newmark;
    }

    total += mark;
    if (mark >= 50)
    {
      gt50Count++;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("sum = " + total);
  double average = (total / 5) * 1.00;
  Console.WriteLine("average = " + average);
  Console.WriteLine("Greater or equal to 50 count = " + gt50Count);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @KellyKolesky Your average is still broken.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest *extracting a method*: do not cram everything into a single `Main`:

```
   private static int readMark() {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");

     int result = 0;

     while (true) 
       if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
         Console.WriteLine("Incorrect syntax, enter your mark again");
       else if (result < 0 || result > 100)
         Console.WriteLine("Mark should be in [0..100] range, enter your mark again");   
       else
         return result;
   }
```

Then let's read all the marks into a *collection*, say, an array:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
     int[] marks = new int[5];

     for (int i = 0; i < marks.Length; ++i)
       marks[i] = readMark();
   }
```

Now it's time for the *statistics*. Usually we use *Linq* for this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
     ...
     double average = marks.Average();
     int sum = marks.Sum();
     int countGreaterThan50 = marks.Count(item => item > 50);
```

But we can put a good old `for` / `foreach` loop for this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
     ...
     int total = 0;
     countGreaterThan50 = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < marks.Length; ++i) {
       total += marks[i];

       if (marks[i] > 50) 
         countGreaterThan50 += 1;
     }      

     // (double) total - be careful with integer division:
     // 91 / 5 == 18 when 91.0 / 5 == 18.2  
     double average = ((double) total) / marks.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the way you check if your mark is invalid to a while loop. With just that if check, if the user inserts invalid values consecutively, your code will accept it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int total = 0;
    int marksAbove50Count = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");
        int mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (mark > 100 || mark < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark,Enter your mark again");
            int newmark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            mark = newmark;
        }
        total += mark;
        if(mark >= 50) marksAbove50Count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("sum = " + total);
    double average = (total / 5) * 1.00;
    Console.WriteLine("average = " + average);
    Console.WriteLine("Marks above 50 count: " + marksAbove50Count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```